# Analyzing Time complexity of union-find Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, union-find

Please give a brief and simple approach to analyzing time complexity of the union-find algo. In the two cases
 1. Standard Approach
 2. Weighted-union heuristic Approach

I know in the standard version its time complexity is: **O(n^2)**
and in case of Weighted-union heuristic Approach it is: **O(m + n logn)**

But I'm not getting, how it is coming.
Assumption: Consider there are n elemetns and Linked list data structure with each node pointing to the head of the list, m=make set operations.

Comment: Check Robert Sedgewick/Kevin Wayne book on Algorithms (4th edition). Section 1.5

Comment: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal, the link that u gave didn't analyze the algo.

Answer (score 1):

First some definitions: *m* is the number of make-set operations. *n* is the sum of union/find operations.

**Standard Version**

Assuming that `join(a,b)` makes `b` the root of `a`.

If have a calling sequence of *0.5n* calls like `joint(1,2)`, `joint(2,3)`, `joint(3,4)` you can make a chain of *0.5n* nodes with `1` in the buttom. Then `find(1)` will take *0.5n* time, so calling that *0.5n* times and your runtime will be *0.25n^2=O(n^2)*

As we must do *m* `makeset` operations we end up with O(m+n^2).

**Weighted-Union**

I assume the weight the size of the set (as opposed to rank).

For a given set let *h* be the height of the tree representing it and *w* its size. `find` takes at most *h* time in that set. By induction we can prove that the *h<=log(w)*.

For a single node which has *w=1* and *h=0* the formula trivially holds.

Now consider a join between two tree *a* and *b*, where *a* becomes the new root. Assuming *h<=log(w)* holds for *a* and *b* we will show it also holds for the union. We know that *wa>=wb => wab = wa+wb >= 2wb*. If *a* is strictly taller than *b* we have *hab = ha <= log(wa) <= log(wab)*. Otherwise (when *hb >= ha*) we have  *hab = 1+hb <= 1+log(wb) = log(2wb) <= log(wab)*

This proves that *h<=log(w)* holds. In less mathematical terms we have prove that the height of any set is less than the logarithm of its size, so a find takes at most *O(log(k))* time where k is the size of the set.

Let *j* be the number of union operations. Each `union` touches 2 elements, so the maximal size of any set is bounded by *2j*.

The runtime of the union and finds is therefore *O(j+k log(2j)) = O(n + n log(2n)) = O(n log(n))*. Again we must do *m* `makeset`s, so in total we get *O(m + n log(n))*

Comment: what is make-set operation?